# GTK: Creating a button with GtkWidget does not work all the time

Tags: button, gtk

I have 2 machines that run different versions of Ubuntu (and possibly for GTK itself), and the to display a button works in one machine but not the other.

In one machine it works fine, but on my other machine, the code gets triggered but no button appears and no error is generated. This is the code that I am using to generate the button:

```
static void addDeviceLabels(GtkWidget *widget, vector<device>* connectedDevices, inputData * data)
{
    GtkWidget *deviceButton;
    /* Create the string here (not shown) */
    const gchar * gdevice = (gchar*)(str.c_str());

    deviceButton = gtk_button_new_with_label(gdevice);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(deviceButton), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(connectToDevice), (gpointer) &data);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(data->deviceLabelBox), deviceButton, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(deviceButton);
}
```

I initially, I create a struct as follows:

```
struct inputData {
    GtkWidget *ip;
    GtkWidget *pr;
    GtkWidget *deviceLabelBox;
};

struct inputData input;
```

Main then calls:

```
g_signal_connect(refreshButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(refreshList), &input);
```

and in refreshList:

```
static void refreshList(GtkWidget *widget, inputData * data)
{
    /* .... */
    addDeviceLabels(widget, connectedDevices, data);
}
```

I hope it is allowed to create a button from within a signal, but it works on one machine.

I am not sure why this code works on one machine but not the other. I am sure "addDeviceLabels" gets triggered and my string is identical. Could it be a bug with GTK or is my code incorrect please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: hmmm ... `Main then calls:` is not right; You are just registering a callback on signal `"clicked"` for the button. The function is called when `refreshButton` is "clicked". Are you clicking on the button in both the cases? Absolutely no warning or critical messages when program executes?

Comment: None. I realized this happens because the container is a scrollbar, but if I change it to a traditional container it works. This is strange.

Comment: I guess you mean GtkScrolledWindow. AFAIK GtkScrollBar is not a container. By traditional container do you mean boxs & windows? But the issue is strange, btw what versions of Gtk? Also what are you adding into Scrolled Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your deviceLabelBox is visible?  I.e. are it and all of its parent containers visible up to the toplevel window?

You are doing

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(deviceButton), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(connectToDevice), (gpointer) &data);
```

The last argument is wrong; you want

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(deviceButton), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(connectToDevice), (gpointer) data);
```

i.e. without the "&" in "&data".  You want to pass the value of the data pointer, not the address of the "data" argument.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this mistake.